# Check if WorkRequest has happened last day

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to check whether enqueued work requests (share common suffix, but different prefix) have happened during last day? How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean with "share common suffix"?
WorkRequest can be identified by their `id`, by their `TAG` or, for unique work, by the unique work name.
Once you have the identifier, you can get a WorkInfo of your workrequest and see their status. I don't think that WorkManager keep tracks of when the WorkRequest has been queued.

Comment: I meant unique work name. Thanks.